# Chrome Dev Tools Debugging Ionic Capacitor Angular app with Source Maps

Tags: debugging, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using Ionic 6, Capacitor 4, Angular 14, in an Nx Workspace (using VSCode fwiw).

1. I build my app in VSCode via Nx `nx build my-app --configuration development`.
2. I run `npx cap copy && npx cap sync` on the project command line.
3. I run `npx cap open android` to open the Android Studio project.
4. I choose the menu Build => Make Project in Android Studio.
5. I choose the menu Build => Run (with my USB-connected phone as the target).
6. I open Chrome browser, navigate to chrome://inspect, then Inspect my mobile app to open Chrome Dev Tools.
7. I ctrl+shift+f to find something in my source code to set a breakpoint on, and it goes to a Babel-compiled js file instead of a ts file.
8. I conclude that somehow source maps aren't working for some reason.

It's not *impossible* to debug in this way, but it is much less enjoyable than I know it could be. Can anyone help me figure out where things are going wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `--inline` option on `npx cap sync` command

```
npx cap sync --inline
```

Note, you don’t need to run `npx cap copy` since sync does copy + update.
If you didn’t install any new plugins you don’t need to run sync every time, just copy, copy also has `--inline` option

```
npx cap copy --inline
```

Comment: I get `error: unknown option '--inline'` using capacitor 4.7.0...

Comment: in response to `npx cap copy --inline`

Comment: did `npm uninstall --save-dev @capacitor/cli` on my project and `npm uninstall -g @capacitor/cli` then `npm install -g @capacitor/cli` and then it worked as expected

Comment: unfortunately... still getting babel-looking code in dev tools :-/

Comment: Is your tooling generating source maps? —inline will only work if you already have source maps generated, it will pick them and inline them in the files

Comment: Pretty sure, the Nx development config specifies it should... They would be in the dist folder right?

Comment: Yeah, the should be in the dist folder, make sure they are there

Comment: yep, I do see lots of .map files in the dist folder... hrm